# MDBs and dupe messages

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, message-driven-bean

Let's pretend that an MDB has received a message and has started processing it in a CMT/Required transaction and let's assume that the transaction might take some time to complete.

In such a scenario, would it be possible for a duplicate message to be received and processed by another MDB instance in another transaction, while the first transaction is still in progress?

Or will the container ensure that while an MDB is busy processing a message in a CMT/Required transaction, no other MDB instance will receive a dupe of that same message?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect any message to be locked while part of a transaction, and duplicates shouldn't be sent, as the JMS specification requires:

> 4.4.15 Duplicate Production of Messages:
>   JMS providers must never produce duplicate messages. This means that a
>   client that produces a message can rely on its JMS provider to insure the
>   consumers of the message will only receive it once.

so I think you can rely on the messaging provider to ensure that the MDB does not receive a second copy of the message unless the first is either explicitly rolled back or the transaction is timed out and implicitly rolled back. Both of these operations should 'unlock' the message and make it available for redelivery to the MDB, with JMSRedelivered set to true and JMSXDeliveryCount incremented.

I suspect there are more requirements to supplement the JMS spec in one (or more) of the EJB, JCA or JTA specifications (or J2EE, for that matter), I haven't checked.

Comment: `4.4.15 Duplicate Production of Messages: JMS providers must never produce duplicate messages. This means that a client that produces a message can rely on its JMS provider to insure the consumers of the message will only receive it once.` is this about `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` or in general? Because in `DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE` I think the JMS provider can send dupes. And in MDBs all acknowledgement modes are ignored. That's why I am a bit confused.

Comment: General. 4.4.15 only applies within the scope of a unit of work; it's certainly possible for messages to be delivered to a MDB more than once in the event of a transactional rollback. But until the transaction is backed out you will only get one copy. As for DUPS_OK, it is an indication to the provider that that it can do lazy acknowledgement, with the risk that if a crash occurs the acknowledgement might not be recorded and the message may be redelivered following restart. By setting DUPS_OK the client is saying it doesn't mind duplicates this way. But this doesn't apply to the XA/MDB case.

Comment: *4.4.15* is referring to **production**, not **delivery**, of messages. In *4.4.14*, it is mentioned that in the auto acknowledge mode last consumed messages might be redelivered.

Comment: Under XA (i.e. <trans-attribute>Required</trans-attribute>) acknowledge mode is ignored, but 4.4.15 *is* relevant - the provider must not send another copy while the transaction is in-flight. So going back to your original question, it is not possible "for a duplicate message to be received and processed by another MDB instance in another transaction, while the first transaction is still in progress" as the provider must not do this. If the first transaction fails, the message will be redelivered. Note the JMS spec comments on transactional integrity vs. AUTO_ACK - they're not the same.

Comment: I think *4.4.15* is talking about producing and sending of messages by producers/publisher, not their receipt by consumers/subscribers.

Comment: No, it's talking about a JMS *provider* not a *producer*: A JMS provider is the entity which implements JMS for a
messaging product.

Comment: Yes, a JMS provider is responsible for both production and delivery of messages. If you have a look at *4.4.14*, it specifically talks about their *delivery*.

Comment: We're going round in circles, so I don't think any more is constructive. No MDB will receive a duplicate while a transaction is in flight unless the JMS implementation is broken.